# Chaining methods on-demand

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

The title is probably really bad, so sorry for that :/
I have a library that creates users for me with predefined capabilities. Right now that works by doing something like

```
var User = require(...).User;
var user = new User(...);
// user has methods like which are all asymc
user.register(callback);
user.addBla(callback);
```

I also have wrapper methods which work like:

```
lib.createUser.WithBla(callback)
```

however, that naturally does incur a huge number of methods once you think of various combinations etc. So I have two ideas:

1. somehow make those calls chain-able without having to do huge levels of callback-function-juggling. eg. `lib.createUser(callback).WithBla().WithBlub().WithWhatever()...`
2. passing some sort of capabilities like `lib.createUser({Bla:true, Blub:true}, callback)`

however I have not the slightest clue how to actually implement that, considering all those methods are asynchronous and use callbacks (which I cannot change, as they are based on the node-module request).

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: now if you could actually provide examples of how to do it better ... :P
Also the library is not general at all, its only purpose is creating users in specific states for test automation. Sadly this is not a trivial topic and there are many different systems involved.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not quite what you had in mind, but you could use the library [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) for this.

```
var user = new User();
user.addSomeValue = function(someValue, cb) { cb(null) }

// Execute some functions in series (one after another)
async.series([
    // These two will get a callback as their first (and only) argument.
    user.register,
    user.addBla,

    // If you need to pass variables to the function, you can use a closure:
    function(cb) { user.addSomeValue(someValue, cb); }

    // Or use .bind(). Be sure not to forget the first param ('this').
    user.addSomeValue(user, someValue)
], function(err, results) {
    if(err) throw "One of the functions failed!";
    console.log(
        "The the various functions gave these values to the callbacks:",
        results;
    );
});
```

The result is a single callback, not many nested ones.

Another option would be to re-write your code to use [Promises](http://howtonode.org/promises).

Comment: I'll have a look into that (esp. promises which I already know from webdriverjs)